# How to decompress/deaggregate hierarchical data in python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, aggregation

I have some compressed/aggregated data such as

```
Incident_ID Case_ID_1   Name_1  Case_ID_2   Name_2  Common
1   1.1 Peter   1.2 Sally   Apple
2   2.1 Sam 2.2 Juliet  Banana
```

Into this

```
Incident_ID Case_ID Name    Common
1   1.1 Peter   Apple
1   1.2 Sally   Apple
2   1.1 Sam Banana
2   2.1 Juliet  Banana
```

I know how to aggregate data in pandas, but I can't find any example online that does de-aggregation of data like this as far as I know.

Comment: You may want to check `pd.melt`

Comment: Thanks, I will explore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Incident_ID','Common'])

df_case = df1[['Case_ID_1','Case_ID_2']].stack().reset_index(level=2,drop=True).rename('Case')

df_name = df1[['Name_1','Name_2']].stack().reset_index(level=2,drop=True).rename('Name')

df_out = pd.concat([df_case,df_name], axis=1).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   Incident_ID  Common  Case_ID    Name
0            1   Apple      1.1   Peter
1            1   Apple      1.2   Sally
2            2  Banana      2.1     Sam
3            2  Banana      2.2  Juliet
```